# Can we use primary key in data (unique values) as _id field of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongo-shell, mongoimport

Suppose, I have a CSV file containing data of students. Columns in data are like-

1. Student_ID
2. Student_Name
3. Address

Here I have Student_ID which is primary key i.e. unique throughout the table. Can I use Student_ID as a _id field in MongoDB while importing?

If Yes then - How?

If No then - Why?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use the `Student_ID` field in your document **instead** of the `_id`? (In other words, your document would not have an `_id` field but, instead, just a `Student_ID` field?)

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I mean. Instead of another unique value column `_id`, Can I simply use my column `Student_ID`?

Answer (score 1):

Just send `Student_ID` as value to the `_id key` in your insert command
like:

```
db.class.insert({’_id’:'Student_ID_value', 'Student_Name':'MyNameHere'})
```

Comment: Yes that is a way but for this I have to iterate over all the records in CSV and insert them one by one. Is there any method to specify such thing while using MongoDBImport?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **[mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)** to import your CSV file, then you cannot specify a way in the command to override the `_id` field with your `Student_ID` field.

Thus, when importing, MongoDB will automatically create an `_id` field for each record and assign it a unique ObjectID. For inserts, this is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#id-field):

> If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add
>   the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before
>   inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field,
>   but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or
>   application does not.

If your CSV file does **not** contain an `_id` field already then the `_id` field will be added to the collection (along with your Student_ID, Student_Name and Address fields) upon importing.

---

If you want the `Student_ID` field to be the `_id` field then you could rename the Student_ID column in the CSV file to _id and then do the mongoimport.

---

If you really just want to have your `Student_ID` field *behave* like a primary key then consider making a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-unique/) on the Student_ID field. That way, like a primary key, no duplicate values will occur. For example:

```
db.<yourcollection>.createIndex( { "Student_ID": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```